# View file when node is viewed

Tags: nodes

Lets say I have a node type that has a file field(docx,pdf etc). Is there a way to get drupal to show the file directly on node view instead of having the user to navigate to the node and then click on the file to view it?

Answer (score 0):

The [PDF Reader](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_reader) module sounds like what you're looking for.